# Is it possible to change Xcode's default location for iOS .xcarchive bundles?

Tags: xcode4, build, xcodebuild

Xcode creates its .xcarchive bundles here:  `"~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/ProjName MM-DD-YY h.mm AM.xcarchive"`

This is fine for an individual developer, but it's not so cool for an automated build in a controlled workspace, one that has to copy every production build's xcarchive(s) to a posting location.

Is it possible, on the xcodebuild command line, to change the target directory for writing the .xcarchive bundle? I've done a lot of searching and nobody else seems to be asking this question. I can find a lot of info that tells me what I've already told you, but nothing about modifying the home of .xcarchive bundles. I have tried changing DSTROOT and SRCROOT.

Thanks.

Comment: It can't be done from the command line. We ended up moving the directory from the area defined in Xcode's Location preferences (see Mark's answer below) into the build workspace postbuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Xcode's Location preferences to change the default location for archives.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is one way. Agreed. But I should have explained better. How about a way to do it on the fly, so that the Archives can be written to a sandbox/workspace in an automated build system (and thus will be discarded when that workspace is cleaned, amongst other benefits) ?